# Some questions about symbol and instance method in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web, methods, symbols

I'm currently try to learn ruby on 'Learn Ruby The Hard Way'
Here's my question...

The following code are from exercise 40:

```
cities = {'CA'=> 'San Francisco', 'MI'=> 'Detroit', 'FL'=> 'Jacksonville'}

cities['NY'] = 'New York'
cities['OR'] = 'Portland'

def find_city(map, state)
  if map.include? state
    return map[state]
  else
    return 'Not found.'
  end
end

cities[:find] = method(:find_city)

while true
  print 'State? (ENTER to quit) '
  state = gets.chomp

  break if state.empty?

  puts cities[:find].call(cities, state)
end
```

I played around with the code, and finally understand how it works.
But I still don't understand about two things:

first...

In about middle of the code,
it defined a variable

```
cities[:find] = method(:find_city)
```

As what I know for now, the `:`(colon) declare a symbol.
I want to know is it a better practice to name a variable as `cities[:find]`
instead of using `cities_find` in this case?

I'm not quite sure what's the differences, or maybe it's much readable for most rubyist?

And the second one is also about the same line.

```
method(:find_city)
```

I know it allows me to call the `find_city` method.
But again, why I have to put a colon before `find_city`?
Does this code means parse the arguments I put in to symbols?

Answer (score 2):

I have to say that *Learn Ruby The Hard Way* gives us a really Really REALLY GOOD example of what we should NOT do. No rubyist will ever type such code in his/her projects. This piece of code is confusing, unreadable and is an abuse of metaprogramming.

Anyway, I dissect that code for you.

The confusing part starts with this line:

```
cities[:find] = method(:find_city)
```

Let's look at the right side of the `=`. It calls a method whose name is `method`, as you may guess, the return value of the method call is the method `find_city`, more precisely, a `Method` object that wraps the method `find_city` with its scope. Then that method is stored in the hash `cities`, with a symbol `:find` as the key. So the value of `cities` now become

```
{
  'CA'=> 'San Francisco', 
  'MI'=> 'Detroit', 
  'FL'=> 'Jacksonville',
  'NY' => 'New York',
  'OR' => 'Portland',
  :find => #<Method:main.find_city>
}
```

You can see that the last key-value pair is really really weird, and it shouldn't be there because the hash `cities` should only store states and their capitals. Heck!

Then here comes this even weirder expression `cities[:find].call(cities, state)`. Let's see how this work.

`cities[:find]` simply retrieve the `Method` object from the hash (still remember what method it wraps?)

`cities[:find].call(cities, state)` invokes the method it wraps, which is `find_city`, in the scope that the `Method` object wraps, which is the top level object (a.k.a. `main`), `Method#call` returns whatever the method wrapped in returns. So this expression is just `find_city(cities, state)`, written in an alien style.

Comment: `written in an alien style` :D +1!

Answer (score 0):

> `cities[:find] = method(:find_city)`

Here, `cities` is a hash and the method object returned by `method(:find_city)` is assigned to the hash key `find` which is a symbol.

I think it depends upon you and the context of program where you are writing this.

A simple `method_var =  method(:find_city)` would work here as well.

---

> `method(:find_city)`
>
> I know it allows me to call the find_city method. But again, why I have to put a colon before find_city? Does this code means parse the arguments I put in to symbols?

Here, you are passing the method name as an argument, you have to either pass it as a `symbol` or `string`.

Answer (score 0):

In Ruby, the `method` method creates a Method Object. This allow you to pass it around in your code and call it later using the `.call` method on your Method object.
Since calling `method(my_method)` would evaluate `my_method` and pass the result to `method(...)`, you need a way to tell the `method` method which method to use. That's why you basically pass in the method name as a Symbol into the `method` method :D

Answer (score -2):

So it actually defined a `proc`, and make `:find` and `find_city` sort like key and value...Probably...